# Vbscript for automated website login testing

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, vbscript

I am trying to run a vbscript, that would do following:

1. Launch IE and load website.
2. Login to the website.
3. Verifies whether the login was success or not.

Now I have got the script that deals with part 1 and 2. Its part 3, i.e. verify login success that I am stuck with. How do I do this?

Here is the code I got off some forum:

```
 Dim IE
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Visible = 1 
 IE.navigate "https://my.website.com"
 Do While (IE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 10
 Loop
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formUsername")
 Helem.Value = "username" ' change this to yours
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formPassword")
 Helem.Value = "password" ' change this to yours
 Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(0)
 Helem.Submit
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to verify login success at this high a level is probably to search for an element  in the HTML that only appears when logged in. If that exists assume you're logged in, if it doesn't try to navigate and log in again.

Here is a very simple example that uses Len() to check if an element containing text exists. You can be more sophisticated if you want and do things like verify that the information you're seeing matches what you would see if you were logged in.

You can use the same functions you used above to grab elements and then compare any of their members.

```
Dim IE
Dim Helem

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate "http://www.example.com"

Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formUsername")
Helem.Value = "username" ' change this to yours
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formPassword")
Helem.Value = "password" ' change this to yours
Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(0)
Helem.Submit

Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop

Dim someElement
Set someElement = IE.document.getElementByID("someElement")

If Len(someElement.innerText) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "logged in"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Francis, it would be great if there is a sample code, that would look for, say link on the page that says "Logout". Sorry for asking this, but I am really new with this stuff!

Comment: I edited this to show you how you might get this to work using a simple Len() to verify.

Comment: Wow, this looks like something I can definitely use! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do

- If the website returns a error message like "Login failed" or "Bad Password" you could check the body for that specific text

```
    If inStr(lcase(IE.document.body.innertext), "bad login") then
      'Do error checking here
    End If
```

- If the title tag changes once you log in, you could also check for that to verify that you have been logged in.

Comment: That's a really helpful suggestion, Dan! The first example will help me authenticate whether login was success or not to an extent. For the second option, is there a code that would show me how that can be done, that would be really awesome!

Comment: Thanks Dan, I will try with that option as well.

Comment: I liked Dan's answer but for my purpose... you may have to remove lcase as such                                                                                             `If inStr(IE.Document.body.innertext, "Please sign in.") then
      'Do error checking here
   MsgBox("element does exist")
   else
   MsgBox("element does not exist")
    End If`