# Automate login using VB script getting error code "80010108"

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to automate an application login using the following VB script. I   successfully login to the web page but afterwards i need to click a button in the web page.

Code:

```
Const strURL = "xxx"  
Const strID = "yyy"   
Const strPswd = "zzz" 
Set IE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate strURL
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys strID
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys strPswd
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
IE.getElementsByname("Button Name").Click
```

But i am getting error like `"The object invoked has disconnected from its client". 
code80010108 source :Null`

Comment: Avoid of using `SendKeys` method. Try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16441367/3439404) instead. In breaf: `IE.Document.getElementById("xxx").Value = strID` and `IE.Document.getElementById("yyy").Value = strPswd` and (`IE.Document.all("zzz").Click` or `IE.document.Forms(0).Submit`). Change `xxx`, `yyy` and `zzz` to real IDs of corresponding elements.

Comment: @JosefZ: i am able to login to the webpage without any issues.But what I need is to click a button which is in the next webpage after login.

Comment: Yes, I see you are able to login to the webpage, but navigating with keyboard (the same as `SendKeys`) or mouse causes disconnecting from `IE` object handle...

Answer (score 0):

```
I Resolved the issue with below changes in code.

Option Explicit
Dim IE,objShell
set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 6000
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "URL"
Do While IE.Busy
Loop
IE.Document.getElementByID("sign_up").Click
WScript.Sleep 1000

Const strID = "email"
Const strPswd = "pwd"
Const loginname = "xxx"
WScript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys loginname
WScript.Sleep 3000
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000 
objShell.SendKeys strID
WScript.Sleep 3000
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys strPswd
WScript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```