# Automating a routine procedure in Windows 10 (Mostly interacting with the browser)

Tags: javascript, windows, vbscript, automation

I'm trying to figure out if I can automate the following tasks,

1. Open the IE
2. Navigate to a site
3. Enter login and password
4. From the user page - Search XXX
5. Right click on the returned result
6. From the drop down menu Left click save
7. Save to a designated folder

I need to repeat this task for 500 times, what's the best way to go about it? I'm thinking of creating a VB Script but not sure if I can do all above with it..

I also found that this can be done in javascript as well? but I don't even know where to start from.

Can someone please give me the right direction? thanks,

Comment: Depending on how complicated the system is, recording the GET/POST requests with fiddler & then recreating them in code _may_ be possible, but without any details i cant say for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you can do it with the Windows Script Host using VBScript or JScript (doesn't matter), using the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object.

For details, check this thread: [Vbscript for automated website login testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441179/vbscript-for-automated-website-login-testing)
See also the MSDN documentation about the IE object model: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx

VBScript example by Francis MacDonald copied from the other thread:

> ```
> Dim IE
> Dim Helem
>
> Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
> IE.Visible = 1 
> IE.navigate "http://www.example.com"
>
> Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formUsername")
> Helem.Value = "username" ' change this to yours
> Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formPassword")
> Helem.Value = "password" ' change this to yours
> Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(0)
> Helem.Submit
>
> Do While (IE.Busy)
>     WScript.Sleep 10
> Loop
>
> Dim someElement
> Set someElement = IE.document.getElementByID("someElement")
>
> If Len(someElement.innerText) > 0 Then
>     MsgBox "logged in"
> End If
> ```

2) There is a tool designed specifically for this task which may help you further: [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Thnks alot! This is really helpful.