# copy all text from a webpage and paste into a created text file with time stamp using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have been assigned a task of copying text from a webpage and pasting it on a textfile hourly. And that text file should have date and time. For example if I take the reading on 24th May 2018 at 9AM then the file name should be 24May09AM or 24-5-09. AM/PM isn't mandatory as 24 hour time format can be used. I know how to open the website using vbscript and also create a text file using the date and time part. I dont know how to get the text from website to copy. Also the way I take the reading is I log into the webapp url and modify the url to get the health reading. Example : the url is https://client/comp/acct/Userlogin. I enter the log in credentials and hit enter. After logging in the url becomes :
https://client/comp/acct/Home. Then I replace Home with Health and get the health reading of the app. So the url becomes : https://client/comp/acct/Health  and this page has only text.

I cant install Autoit or any other tools in office system.

The 2 things I know are : one - how to create a text file using date and time

```
fnmt = Day(Now()) & "_" & Month(Now()) & "_" & Right(Hour(Now()),2)
fpath = ("E:\Test_Health_Monitor\" & fnmt & ".txt")

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(fpath)
```

Two - how to open the app url from vbs file

```
set w=wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
w.run "iexplore.exe"
wscript.sleep (1000)
w.SendKeys "{F6}"
w.SendKeys "https://client/comp/acct/Userlogin"
w.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
wscript.sleep (7500)
rem w.SendKeys "(username)"
rem w.SendKeys "{TAB}"
rem wscript.sleep (1000)
rem w.SendKeys "(password)"
w.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Now I dont know how to edit the url after logging in and then copy all the text to the created text file. Please help or guide to some pointers.

Comment: you could try automating ie directly, instead of using sendkeys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441179/vbscript-for-automated-website-login-testing

Comment: I figured as much as to how to login to a webapp. I have pasted my snippet code too. But the thread you have posted or shared mentions no where how to edit the url after logging in - no guide in that direction too.

Comment: once logged in, you would use `ie.navigate "<url>"` to go to whatever page you wanted