# vbscript to autofill the online webpage using IE

Tags: javascript, powershell, vbscript

I'm new to vb scripts. Doing an automation for data entry in an online webpage. Below script opens a website but does not enter the value and click search to fetch the case. Could someone help be to debug below script?

Below is the HTML source which has the id for the text box where data has to be entered

```
Dim URL 
Dim IE 
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
URL = "https://ecms.corporate/" 
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL


Do While IE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop


IE.document.getElementById("Request").value="231320"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you are new to VBS and new to this site. This resource is for PowerShell assistance, not VBS. So, though many of us know VBS, that is not what we are here to help with.

As for your use case. There are lots of examples all over the web on how to do this in several languages. Yet, since we are PowerShell focused here, this is how this is done in PowerShell.

First you have to know the actual element you are working with and you do not show how you are getting that. Are you sure you are using the right page elements for your site - To be sure. Navigate the site form elements, not the Internet Explorer elements

```
# Discover all page/form and elements to work with

$url = 'https://pwpush.com'
($FormElements = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable fe) 
($Form = $FormElements.Forms[0]) | Format-List -Force
$Form | Get-Member 
$Form.Fields

# Interact with the site page

$password = '1234'
$loginUrl = 'https://pwpush.com'

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($loginUrl)

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

($ie.document.getElementById('password_payload') | 
select -first 1).value = $password
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

$ie.Document.getElementsByName('commit').Item().Click();
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```

Though this answer in a PowerShell one, the process, if you are stuck using VBS is the same, but just using the VBS methods, as discussed here:

[Vbscript for automated website login testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441179/vbscript-for-automated-website-login-testing)

Comment: Thank you for the details! Yes i'm new and learning a bit everyday. I was able to figure out the initial steps. Will use your inputs further to complete rest of the script. It is interesting.

Comment: No worries, we all have to begin at something, sooner or later.